# Update when MathML is loaded

Tags: jquery, mathml

For some reason MathML isn't getting the .css() update, and I was wondering if there's a way to check when the MathML is loaded so this can be updated?

> http://jsfiddle.net/njz7xaek/

The code shows the problem; the MathML-code isn't updated and stays red, whereas it should become blue, just as the text sample.

HTML

```
<span class="col1">text</span>
<br />
<math>
  <mi class="col1">a</mi>
  <mi>x</mi>
  <mo>+</mo>
  <mi class="col1">b</mi>
</math>
```

CSS

```
.col1 {
  color:red;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.col1').css('color', 'blue');
});
```

Is there a way to make the .css() function trigger after the MathML has loaded, so it can change it as well? It seems to me that .css() happens before this, so MathML isn't affected by it. I was hoping for a simple solution like

```
$(MathML).ready(function() {
  $('.col1').css('color', 'blue');
});
```

But this didn't seem to work...

Comment: Mi elements don't seem to have any inline style associated with them. If you run http://jsfiddle.net/njz7xaek/4/ you'd get something like `els[i].style` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem that the `<mi>` element has any inline style definition associated with it, for example if you do `$("mi")[0].style` you'd get an undefined error.

There's a messy workaround for this by doing something like:

```
var nStyle = $('<style>.col1 { color: blue; }</style>');

$("html > head").append(nStyle);
```

This will create a "global" style tag and append it to the head.

Example at: http://jsfiddle.net/njz7xaek/5/ (needs Firefox)

Comment: I have no idea why, but it seems to work when I render it with MathJax. I'm guessing it includes some features, but I'm a newbie at this and I'm still learning. Your solution is above my understanding and not really preferable at what I'm doing, but it solves the problem so I'll accept it!

Comment: Firefox's MathML implementation suffers from several missing base APIs, including `style`. WebKit suffers from other issues. To answer Frank, MathJax does not use MathML except internally; it converts it to HTML+CSS or SVG. In both cases, `color` will have the desired effect but not all CSS will survive the process (though all of MathML's own styling primitiex should make it).